# Question to find all strictly increasing $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ mapping only primes to primes and satisfying $f(2n)=f(n)+n$ for all $n$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a function such that
>
> 1. $f(m)<f(n)$ whenever $m<n$;
> 2. $f(2n)=f(n)+n$ for all natural numbers $n$;
> 3. $n$ is a prime number whenever $f(n)$ is a prime number.
>
> Find all functions $f$ satisfying above conditions with proof.

I have noticed that the identity function is a solution. I am however, unable to prove this result. To start off I am unable to prove $f(1)=1$, so I'm unable to proceed by induction. I am also not able to effectively use the third condition of the question. I request somebody to please provide a solution for this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What exactly cannot you prove? That identity function is a solution?

Comment: You need to prove that it is the only solution. Also, I haven't even proved that the identity function is a solution... i have not completed the inductive process

Comment: Please read more carefully

Comment: I read carefully. You did not write that you aim is to prove that the identity function is the only solution.

Comment: Ok...ill make the required edits.

Comment: I hope its fine now @user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will prove $f(1)=1$, hence by induction you can take it further to show that $f(n)=n ~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

---

Observe that $$f(n)=f(1)+n-1$$ satisfies the conditions of the functional equation. Now, suppose $f(1)=k>1$.

Next observe that all of the numbers $(k+1)!+2,(k+1)!+3,\cdots,(k+1)!+(k+1)$ are composite numbers (why?). Now, if $p$ is the smallest prime greater than $(k+1)!+(k+1)$, then plugging $n=p-k+1$ yields $f(n)=p$. Therefore, $n$ is a prime number. Now because $k>1$, we have $n=p-k+1<p$ and we conclude $(k+1)!+2<n<p$.

Now note that $p$ was defined to be the smallest prime exceeding $(k+1)! + (k+1)$, and since $(k+1)!+2,(k+1)!+3,\cdots,(k+1)!+(k+1)$ are all composite, means it is also the smallest prime exceeding $(k+1)!+1$. But $n$ was supposed to also be a prime less than $p$ but more than $(k+1)! + 1$. This contradicts that $p$ is the smallest prime exceeding $(k+1)!+(k+1)$ which implies it is impossible to have $f(1)>1$.

Comment: Certainly the new functional equation you introduced implies the first two conditions. But you did not prove that every function which satisfies the latter conditions satisfies the functional equation.

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$f(2)=f(1)+1, \quad f(4)=f(2)+2=f(1)+3$$
and, being $f$ strictly increasing $f(3)=f(1)+2$. By induction you can then prove that
$$f(n)=f(1)+n-1.$$

But then, if $f(1)>1$, $n$ should be prime whenever $n+f(1)-1$ is prime, which is impossible.